# How does PyTables indexing compare to pandas HDFStore (PyTables) indexing

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables, hdfstore

The PyTables library and the HDFStore object (based on PyTables) both provide indexing for the user.

For PyTables alone, we create an HDF5 file as follows (from the documentation):

```
from tables import *

class Particle(IsDescription):
    identity = StringCol(itemsize=22, dflt=" ", pos=0)  # character String
    idnumber = Int16Col(dflt=1, pos = 1)  # short integer
    speed    = Float32Col(dflt=1, pos = 2)  # single-precision

# Open a file in "w"rite mode
fileh = open_file("objecttree.h5", mode = "w")

# Get the HDF5 root group
root = fileh.root

# Create the groups
group1 = fileh.create_group(root, "group1")
group2 = fileh.create_group(root, "group2")

# Now, create an array in root group
array1 = fileh.create_array(root, "array1", ["string", "array"], "String array")

# Create 1 new tables in group1
table1 = fileh.create_table(group1, "table1", Particle)

# Get the record object associated with the table:
row = table1.row

# Fill the table with 10 records
for i in xrange(10):
    # First, assign the values to the Particle record
    row['identity']  = 'This is particle: %2d' % (i)
    row['idnumber'] = i
    row['speed']  = i * 2.

    # This injects the Record values
    row.append()

# Flush the table buffers
table.flush()

# Finally, close the file (this also will flush all the remaining buffers!)
fileh.close()
```

Users index columns by using "Column.create_index()"

For example:

```
indexrows = table.cols.var1.create_index() 
indexrows = table.cols.var2.create_index() 
indexrows = table.cols.var3.create_index()
```

For the latter case, users instantiate an HDFStore object and then chose which columns to index.

```
store = HDFStore('file1.hd5')
key = "key_name"
index_columns = ["column1", "column2"]
store.append(key,... data_columns=index_columns)
```

Here we index on two columns, which should optimize our search.

Two questions:

(1) It is actually not clear to me how to set the indices (indexes) in the PyTables example (the first example). There are no columns defined above. To my mind, there are three fields: identity, idnumber, speed. Let's say I wanted to place an index on speed and identity. How would one do this?

(2) Are there any benchmarks between the the pandas based indexing and PyTables based indexing? Is one faster than the other? Does one take up more disk space (i.e. larger HDF5 file) than the other?